# Protestantism: If justification is by faith alone how can judgement be by works?

Tags: protestantism, judgment, justification, sola-fide

The idea of justification seems to come often in Paul, Romans 3:20:

> Therefore by the deeds of the law there shall no flesh be justified in
> his sight: for by the law is the knowledge of sin

Jesus affirms something even more bluntly, John 5:24:

> “Very truly I tell you, whoever hears my word and believes him who
> sent me has eternal life and will not be judged but has crossed over
> from death to life.

However, why does justification even matter, and how is it that the justified are not even coming into judgement, since, everything seems to end up in judgement anyways:
Romans 2:6

> God “will repay each person according to what they have done.”

Jesus (Matthew 7:21):

> Not everyone who says to me 'Lord, Lord,' will enter the kingdom of
> heaven, but only the one who does the will of my Father in heaven.

Comment: John 5:24 is better rendered '_He that heareth my word, and believeth on him that sent me, hath everlasting life, and shall not come into **condemnation** ; but is passed from death unto life._' All are judged. Some are condemned and some are justified.

Comment: Another important verse to consider here is 2 Corinthians 5:10: "For we must all appear before the judgment seat of Christ, so that each one may receive what is due for what he has done in the body, whether good or evil."

Comment: @LarsH 2 Cor 5:10 is regarding service of believers, not salvation of anyone (as can be seen in verse 9 on "labor").  See also 1 Cor chapter 3.  1 Cor 3:15 "If any man's work shall be burned, he shall suffer loss: but he himself shall be saved; yet so as by fire."  Our works will be judged and rewarded at the judgement seat of Christ, but we ourselves (believers) "shall be saved".  The judgement seat of Christ is for believers, the White Throne Judgement is for unbelievers.

Comment: @MarkVestal It sounds like you're suggesting that the OP's question was only about salvation?

Comment: @LarsH On the contrary. I'm trying to point out that salvation and works are separate topics. If we are justified then we are saved (by having faith alone). What we do now that we have that gift is where the "works" for reward comes in.  Basically, what did we do with what we knew?

Comment: @MarkVestal I agree with you that salvation and works are separate topics and that we are saved by faith alone. Sorry, I don't understand why you're writing the above in response to my comment about this question. My guess is that you thought I was asserting 2 Cor. 5:10 to be talking about salvation.

Comment: @LarsH You would be right!  lol, peace and grace!

Comment: @MarkVestal My point was just that in order to answer Dan's question, which hinges on judgment and works, we would have to address passages on judgment and works, such as 2 Cor. 5:10.

Comment: @LarsH I understand and see your point now.  I apologize for misunderstandong your intent.

Comment: @MarkVestal Not a problem.

Answer (score 10):

Note that in Matt 7:21, Jesus doesn't say those who enter heaven do so *because* they do the will of the Father, or are without sin, or did good works. He said those that enter heaven are those that do the will of the Father. What do those sets have in common?

James reconciles this:

> 14 What good is it, my brothers and sisters, if someone claims to have faith but has no deeds? Can such faith save them? 15 Suppose a brother or a sister is without clothes and daily food. 16 If one of you says to them, “Go in peace; keep warm and well fed,” but does nothing about their physical needs, what good is it? 17 In the same way, faith by itself, if it is not accompanied by action, is dead.

> 18 But someone will say, “You have faith; I have deeds.” Show me your faith without deeds, and I will show you my faith by my deeds.

So one thing that's true about those who have faith is that they are justified. Another thing that's true about those who have faith is they do good works. "By their fruits ye shall know them." There are those that claim to have faith, but if they aren't doing the good works, that's not real. "Faith without works is dead." They'll be saying "Lord, Lord," but the fact that they aren't doing God's will shows He isn't their Lord and they aren't people of faith.

That may be too strong a case. I don't mean to suggest good works are useless. But as St. Paul points out, we are saved by grace, not works. What shall we do with that grace? He got that grace...and dedicated his life to Christ. We are called to do the same. If we don't, the parable of the sheep and the goats suggests it won't go well for us.

The Romans verse is tougher. St. Paul later in the letter says all have sinned and fallen short of the glory of God. So until we get God's grace, we're in that set that does evil (a few verses down).

Comment: "But as St. Paul points out, we are saved by grace, not works." Where does St. Paul point that out?

Comment: Ephesians 2:8-9.

Comment: _For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God: Not of works, lest any man should boast._ Ephesians 2:8,9 KJV.

Comment: @Maverick Jesus Christ and Him crucified IS the grace of God to the world. Rom 3:24 "Being justified freely by his grace through the redemption that is in Christ Jesus:" Those who will simply believe this are the ones then saved (1 Cor 15:1-4). Forgiveness happened at the cross, salvation happens at the moment of belief. Eph 1:12-13 "That we should be to the praise of his glory, who first trusted in Christ. 13 In whom ye also trusted, after that ye heard the word of truth, the gospel of your salvation: in whom also after that ye believed, ye were sealed with that holy Spirit of promise,"

Answer (score 3):

You start by quoting two scriptures Protestants agree with, verses that declare nobody can be justified in God's sight by deeds of the law, and that believers have [present tense] eternal life, having already passed over from judgment and death, to life. Then you ask:

> **"However, why does justification even matter..?"**

The simple logic as to the importance of God's justification is that - without it - nobody can escape his righteous judgment, and nobody can be moved over from death to life. In view of that, surely obtaining God's free gift of justification matters more than anything else for an individual? Next you ask something that shows why this simple, logical point has been so elusive:

> "**How is it that the justified are not even coming into judgement,
> since, everything seems to end up in judgement anyways?**"

This is where the horse has suddenly been moved from pulling the cart, to being tied behind it, thus the cart stops going forward and grinds to a halt.

Yes, everything and everyone will "end up in judgment" - but those whom God justifies have already accepted his righteous judgment of them in this life, agreeing with him, which leads them to stop trying to justify themselves before him. They confess and repent of all that condemns them before the righteous God, and accept his one and only means of being pardoned. They receive that pardon, freely, and they are justified in God's sight. They then pass out of "the condemned cell" (as it were) being set free because of what Christ did for them to secure their pardon.

Because that has happened to them ***before*** the Day of Resurrection and Judgment, when that awful Day dawns, they will not stand before the Judgment Bar to receive punishment. There will be no case for them to answer because Christ has already acted as their Advocate, proving there is no case for them to answer.

Alas, for all others who strove till the day they died to justify themselves before God, due to what they said they believed and due to what works they did, they still have a case to answer because they did not trust utterly in God's one and only means of receiving a free pardon - faith in the Son of God; following him (as opposed to following any religious system, for example).

Many who claim to have faith in Christ will discover (too late, as Jesus pointed out) that he will not recognize them on that Day as being Christians. A snippet of Mathew 7:21-23 has been cited but all of it shows that 'doing the will of the Father' is not about outward appearances of doing good Christian "things", for Christ will cast them aside as workers of lawlessness. The Father's will is to believe the one he sent, Jesus Christ - and that requires faith:

> "Then said they unto him, What shall we do, that we might work the
> works of God? Jesus answered and said unto them, This is the work of
> God, that ye believe on him whom he hath sent" [Himself.] John 6:28-29
> A.V.

After such a step of believing faith, that person will strive to live acceptably, as 1 John 3:4-10 shows; those who live righteously (as the sons of God) have had their sins taken away. That already having happened, through faith in the sinless One, sin and death no longer enslave them. They have been set free in Christ.

Of course, the Bible does make passing mention of "rewards" in heaven for what those gaining entrance may receive for the good deeds done in the body. **But justification is not a reward! It is a free, unmerited gift of grace.** Having received it, the justified sinner lives to please God and will discover, in glory, how pleased God was regarding all that. As Jesus promised regarding his disciples being persecuted:

> "Fear them not therefore: for there is nothing covered, that shall not
> be revealed; and hid that shall not be known." Matthew 10:26 A.V.

Yes, God righteously judges everything, and everyone, so it is the course of wisdom to confess one's unrighteousness before God prior to the Day of Resurrection and Judgment, so as to be viewed as justified in God's sight now by putting total faith in what Jesus did to enable passing over from judgment to life.

Comment: Yes! It is not about OUR righteousness, it is about God's righteousness and us believing that. A believer has accepted that they are not capable of the "righteousness of God" on their own, but they have accepted God's gift through having faith in Christ BEING their righteousness. We place our faith in Him being the only way to salvation, rather than ANYTHING of ourselves (works). Works come AFTER salvation. Works mean nothing if the one working is doing it as an effort to save themselves. Believers work for God because they ARE saved...not to become saved or to maintain their salvation.

Answer (score 2):

Those who have *experienced* justification have *already been* judged. This experience includes the conviction of sins (the deeds) and the felt acknowledgment of sin (the inward state described in Romans 7 by Paul).

It is this experience of regeneration, including repentance and faith, which is the begetting of the Father in the Holy Spirit and which results in 'being dead to the law by the body of Christ' and 'I am crucified with Christ, nevertheless I live yet not I but Christ liveth in me' and it is this that produces works of faith and love, which, alone, are pleasing to the Father.

These are they who, being judged in the Day of Judgment, as is only proper and right, are seen to be justified, and to have - already - passed from death to life, and have the old man crucified, the rather living unto God.

> For I through the law am dead to the law that I might live unto God [Galatians 2:19 KJV]

I recorded my own experience of justification in a book called '*Jehovah Tsidkenu'* :

> My understanding of what is recorded in holy writ is that which I know in my
> own experience. Having become piercingly aware of my own sinful deeds -
> not that, particularly, of which I had done among men, but what I had done in
> regard to God and his Son - and having become piercingly aware of my own
> sin within, that was impossible to eradicate by any natural means - then I
> reached a time when, aware of a strong response within me, ‘It is God that
> justifieth - who is he that condemneth ?’ then, perforce, I ceased from my
> own works and believed in God who justifies the ungodly.
>
> Having long time, with trembling, believed that I was beyond all hope, that
> only a flaming fire awaited me, inevitably, and having dwelt upon this
> unavoidable fate with torment to the point where I could not refrain from
> the repetitive shaking of my limbs, that strong response from within - It is God that justifeth - was all I had; nothing more.
>
> With that and with nothing else, I sought God, through the flame of well
> deserved wrath. The flaming fire of Divine righteousness was utterly against me.
>
> This was the conflagration of Divine nature. But I cried, I panted, to know the Person of God, within the Nature of God.
>
> I believed that 'with God - all things are possible'.
>
> And so they are. For I have seen that Divine fire fall upon him who offered up
> himself. I have seen the sword of justice pierce the offered sacrifice at
> Golgotha - the one who, through the eternal Spirit, offered himself up to God.
> He whom the Father sent to do his will, yielded - not my will, but thine be
> done.
>
> And in the darkness from the sixth hour until the ninth hour, was that
> will done.

*Jehovah Tsidkenu* (The Lord our Righteousness) pp158-159 *belmontpublications.co.uk*

(Available free of charge and without registration)

Answer (score 0):

Because faith and works are inseparable.

It is not possible to have faith without works.

> Yea, a man may say, Thou hast faith, and I have works: shew me thy faith without thy works, and I will shew thee my faith by my works. (James 2:18)

Faith implies works.

Many verses can easily be taken out of context and cherry-picked if we assume that any few words of Scripture can be taken alone as the final word. But if that were true, then *why does the rest of the Bible exist*? It is a rather extreme take on Sola Scriptura to say that there is only one verse in the Bible that matters, or only a few, and the rest may be discarded. Intelligent questions such as yours have to do with understanding how to reconcile Scripture with itself, which forces us more nearly to comprehend its holistic meaning.

The more we read, the more we find oversimplifications and out of context interpretations rebutted, and our view of the backbone of the Gospel is clarified and expanded:

For example, in Mark 16:16 we read:

> He that believeth and is baptized shall be saved; but he that believeth not shall be damned.

Why did Mark add another condition to John 5:24? Why does one verse say there is one thing we need to do and another says there are two? Well, because there are more things than one that we need to do, and the emphasis of one or a few on one occasion or in one breath do nothing to discount the necessity of others. We are still breathing, there is more to do:

> Whoso walketh uprightly shall be saved: but he that is perverse in his ways shall fall at once. Proverbs 28:18

> The Lord is nigh unto them that are of a broken heart; and saveth such as be of a contrite spirit.  Psalm 34:18

> Then Peter said unto them, Repent, and be baptized every one of you in the name of Jesus Christ for the remission of sins, and ye shall receive the gift of the Holy Ghost. Acts 2:38

The more of Scripture we read, the more a clear picture emerges. Salvation isn't a single piano key or a pushbutton. It's a symphony, and it requires our practice.

Even the immediate follow-on to the implication of works from faith by James clarifies that we must keep reading the Scriptures, that salvation is not a simple one-and-done:

> Thou believest that there is one God; thou doest well: the devils also believe, and tremble. James 2:19

The Scriptures implicitly assume that we will have the good sense to use them together rather than in isolation.

If we believe the Savior and act intelligently on that belief, we will repent of our sins. If we repent of our sins we will be baptized. If we are baptized we will seek and receive the gift of the Holy Ghost, as Peter says. If we receive these things once we must endure in them and abide in the faith, abounding in good works. Otherwise we have no promise of purification or of salvation either.

The Scriptures are intended to be used together, not disjointly.
If we take each verse alone we can make a church for each verse, but there would be no unity and no comprehension.
Only by putting them together can we understand their more complete meaning.

> Man shall not live by bread alone, but by every word that proceeds out of the mouth of God.

The fact that the Lord says one thing does not mean He cannot say another.

As for how this reconciles with being saved by grace, not works:

> For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God: Not of works, lest any man should boast. Ephesians 2:8,9

This is easily understood by the word everyone caught in the grace vs. works debate ignores:

> "and".

"And" is multiplicative. If you do one thing but not the other, you do not obtain the result. You can multiply ever so large a number by zero and you will still get zero. You can multiply ever so small a number, but not zero, by infinity and you will get something really significant. The Savior's Atonement is that big number. It is infinite. Our works are the tiny number. Infinitesimal by comparison, but they are still absolutely required. No sensible person will say he is saved "by" his works in light of the great bounty offered to him by the Lord's sacrifice, but nor can he honestly say that his works are unimportant. If he has faith, he will also have works. If he believes that the Son of God will heal him, he will look at the brazen serpent. Hence God loves and rewards our efforts to follow Him, and it is not "grace **or** works", but "grace **and** works". No man can boast of his works because without Christ, we can do nothing.

We cannot be judged by the Lord's Atonement, because it is His offering, not ours. We can only be judged by what we do with it, how we hold it, and what we do with the opportunities given to us. We are therefore **judged by our works**, but **saved by the Lord's grace**, because of our faith in Him.

Comment: All scripture is profitable for our learning, but not all was written directly to us. We cannot take what was written to one group of people (like biblical Israel) and apply what was to them as being to us. It is perfectly acceptable (and commanded in 2 Tim 2:15) to separate their doctrine from that of our own. All today are on equal ground as far as how salvation is received, and how to live afterwards. What God expected from Israel (and will again someday) often differs from what He expects of us today. We find OUR direct instruction in Paul's epistles, not that of James, John, or Peter.

Comment: The "and that not of yourselves" in Eph 2:8 expands on what "saved" means; to be nothing of ourselves. The same verse further clarifies that it is "Not of works", otherwise one could boast about their works being what saved them. Rom 4:4-5 is in line with this: "Now to him that worketh is the reward not reckoned of grace, but of debt. 5 But to him that worketh not, but believeth on him that justifieth the ungodly, his faith is counted for righteousness." If one then does not do their part and work AFTER salvation, will they lose salvation?  No. They will have "loss of reward" (1 Cor 3:14-15).

Comment: @MarkVestal But if we didn't have to do anything to be saved, then we would all be equally saved with Abraham and the patriarchs or all equally damned with the devils.
Hence the needless conundrum and confusion, which is fully settled by that humble word "and".

Comment: We do have to do something. We have to believe. The use of the word "and" is explanatory, not 'in addition to'. Rather than make Christ's earthly ministry to Israel through their twelve match Christ's heavenly ministry through Paul to us Gentiles, we simply follow what OUR apostle Paul says...as he "beseeches" us to do.  The confusion and contradiction ceases to exist if we study the Bible with the understanding that we are not biblical Israel.  Romans 11:13 "For I speak to you Gentiles, inasmuch as I am the apostle of the Gentiles, I magnify mine office:" This is OUR truth.

Comment: @MarkVestal "and" most definitely spells out additional requirements. "Repent and be baptized". To fall short of the fullness and endurance of faith is an unacceptable substitute for Christianity.

Comment: We will never come to an agreement if not following the same apostle.  Thank you for the dialogue all the same.  Peace and grace!

Comment: @MarkVestal Peace, brother. "Live by every word that proceedeth out of the mouth of God"

Answer (score 0):

Much of what Paul writes is in regard to service, which is separate from salvation.  Our gospel 'good news' is that Jesus Christ was judged on our behalf at the cross:

**2 Corinthians 5:21**

> "For he hath made him to be sin for us, who knew no sin; that we might be made the righteousness of God in him."

Christ's shed blood was the sufficient payment to God for the sins of the world.  This means that those now "in Christ" (believers) are themselves protected from any future wrath or judgement of God.

**2 Corinthians 5:17-19**

> "Therefore if any man be in Christ, he is a new creature: old things are passed away; behold, all things are become new.
> 18 And all things are of God, who hath reconciled us to himself by Jesus Christ, and hath given to us the ministry of reconciliation;
> 19 To wit, that God was in Christ, reconciling the world unto himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed unto us the word of reconciliation."

**1 Thessalonians 5:9-11**

> "For God hath not appointed us to wrath, but to obtain salvation by our Lord Jesus Christ,
> 10 Who died for us, that, whether we wake or sleep, we should live together with him.
> 11 Wherefore comfort yourselves together, and edify one another, even as also ye do."

**Romans 5:6-10**

> "For when we were yet without strength, in due time Christ died for the ungodly.
> 7 For scarcely for a righteous man will one die: yet peradventure for a good man some would even dare to die.
> 8 But God commendeth his love toward us, in that, while we were yet sinners, Christ died for us.
> 9 Much more then, being now justified by his blood, we shall be saved from wrath through him.
> 10 For if, when we were enemies, we were reconciled to God by the death of his Son, much more, being reconciled, we shall be saved by his life."

What will be judged of the believer is their post-salvation service.  It is the quality of their works that is judged and then rewarded on.  The accuracy of the believer's understanding and sharing of Paul's gospel of God's grace and Christ crucified with others is the basis of their reward:

**Romans 2:16**

> " In the day when God shall judge the secrets of men by Jesus Christ according to my gospel."

**Romans 16:25-26**

> "Now to him that is of power to stablish you according to my gospel, and the preaching of Jesus Christ, according to the revelation of the mystery, which was kept secret since the world began,
> 26 But now is made manifest, and by the scriptures of the prophets, according to the commandment of the everlasting God, made known to all nations for the obedience of faith:"

If a believers works are of merit they will receive the reward.  If their works are found unworthy then they will suffer loss of reward.  This has nothing to do with their eternal salvation as is stated below:

**1 Corinthians 3:10-15**

> "According to the grace of God which is given unto me, as a wise masterbuilder, I have laid the foundation, and another buildeth thereon. But let every man take heed how he buildeth thereupon.
> 11 For other foundation can no man lay than that is laid, which is Jesus Christ.
> 12 Now if any man build upon this foundation gold, silver, precious stones, wood, hay, stubble;
> 13 Every man's work shall be made manifest: for the day shall declare it, because it shall be revealed by fire; and the fire shall try every man's work of what sort it is.
> 14 If any man's work abide which he hath built thereupon, he shall receive a reward.
> 15 If any man's work shall be burned, he shall suffer loss: but he himself shall be saved; yet so as by fire."

We are complete and justified through having faith alone in Jesus Christ:

**Colossians 2:8-10**

> "Beware lest any man spoil you through philosophy and vain deceit, after the tradition of men, after the rudiments of the world, and not after Christ.
> 9 For in him dwelleth all the fulness of the Godhead bodily.
> 10 And ye are complete in him, which is the head of all principality and power:"

**Romans 3:28**

> "Therefore we conclude that a man is justified by faith without the deeds of the law."

**Romans 5:1**

> "Therefore being justified by faith, we have peace with God through our Lord Jesus Christ:"

Answer (score -2):

Justification by grace and judged by works - how to reconcile?

> KJV Romans 3:25-26 Whom God hath set forth to be a propitiation through faith in his blood, to declare his righteousness for the **remission of sins that are past**, through the forbearance of God; To declare, I say, at this time his righteousness: that he might be just, and the justifier of him which believeth in Jesus.

Justification by grace happens for past sins only not for the future sins. Once we commit a sin after justification, we have to be converted(receive pardon) again.

> KJV 1 John 2:1-2 My little children, these things write I unto you, that ye sin not. And if any man sin, we have an advocate with the Father, Jesus Christ the righteous: And he is the propitiation for our sins: and not for our's only, but also for the sins of the whole world.

> Luke 22:31-32 And the Lord said, Simon, Simon, behold, Satan hath desired to have you, that he may sift you as wheat: But I have prayed for thee, that thy faith fail not: and when thou art converted, strengthen thy brethren

Jesus plainly told Peter that he has to be converted after his betrayal. If once justifies by grace there is no need for rejustification or reconversion, Christ would not have told this.

Every sin must be repented for, confessed and pardon should be received individually. God plainly stated in Ezekiel, previous righteousness cannot excuse currect sin. In the day we sin, all our righteousness which grace bestows upon us will not be counted anymore. We are counted as sinners. Whosoever commits sin is of the devil 1 John 3:8. Jesus confirmed this when he rebuked Simon "But he turned, and said unto Peter, Get thee behind me, Satan: thou art an offence unto me: for thou savourest not the things that be of God, but those that be of men." Matt 16:23. Then again "Satan has desired to have you". When Peter sinned he had to be born again - born of God, so that he can become righteous again.

> Ezekiel 33:12 Therefore, thou son of man, say unto the children of thy people, The righteousness of the righteous shall not deliver him in the day of his transgression: as for the wickedness of the wicked, he shall not fall thereby in the day that he turneth from his wickedness; neither shall the righteous be able to live for his righteousness in the day that he sinneth.

Again and again the Bible warns us:

> KJV Luke 21:34-36 And take heed to yourselves, lest at any time your hearts be overcharged with surfeiting, and drunkenness, and cares of this life, and so that day come upon you unawares. For as a snare shall it come on all them that dwell on the face of the whole earth. Watch ye therefore, and pray always, that ye may be accounted worthy to escape all these things that shall come to pass, and to stand before the Son of man.

> KJV 1 Corinthians 10:12 Wherefore let him that thinketh he standeth take heed lest he fall.

> KJV 1 Corinthians 9:27 But I keep under my body, and bring it into subjection: lest that by any means, when I have preached to others, I myself should be a castaway.

God gives grace which enables us to obey God and follow His will and overcome the inherited and cultivated tendencies/propensities to sin.

> KJV Ephesians 2:8-10 For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God: Not of works, lest any man should boast. For we are his workmanship, created in Christ Jesus unto good works, which God hath before ordained that we should walk in them.

The end result of Grace is that we are recreated (born again) in Christ Jesus unto good works. If good works are not seen in our lives, then it means we are not born again through grace.

The credit does not belong to us because these works are empowered by Grace and not by our own power. So God alone is to be credited for His Grace. Not of works lest we should boast.

What are the good works that this verse speaks? The word Good when used in relation to spiritual character, has a deeper meaning - not what we mean by that word in our daily usage.

> KJV Matthew 19:17 And he said unto him, Why callest thou me good? there is none good but one, that is, God: but if thou wilt enter into life, keep the commandments.

God's character alone is described as "Good". Interestingly, the commandments are mentioned in the same verse. The Bible describes the commandments as "Good"

> KJV Romans 7:12 Wherefore the law is holy, and the commandment holy, and just, and good.

Thus the Good works are works which do not violate God's law in the spirit.

TLDR: God justifies the past sins through His Grace. But the same grace gives power to overcome sin and keep the commandments and helps us do the "Good Works" which God has foreordained. One cannot receive Grace and continue in sin. If one continues sinning then he/she is not born of God. For he that is born if God *cannot* commit sin, for His (God's) seed remains in him 1 John 3:9

---

Addendum:

> KJV 1 John 3:6-10 Whosoever abideth in him sinneth not: whosoever sinneth hath not seen him, neither known him. Little children, let no man deceive you: he that doeth righteousness is righteous, even as he is righteous. He that committeth sin is of the devil; for the devil sinneth from the beginning. For this purpose the Son of God was manifested, that he might destroy the works of the devil. **Whosoever is born of God doth not commit sin**; for his seed remaineth in him: and **he cannot sin**, because he is born of God. In this the children of God are manifest, and the children of the devil: whosoever doeth not righteousness is not of God, neither he that loveth not his brother.

> 1 John 3:24 And he that keepeth his commandments dwelleth in him, and he in him. And hereby we know that he abideth in us, by the Spirit which he hath given us.

> We do not earn salvation by our obedience; for salvation is the free gift of God, to be received by faith. But obedience is the fruit of faith. "Ye know that He was manifested to take away our sins; and in Him is no sin. Whosoever abideth in Him sinneth not: whosoever sinneth hath not seen Him, neither known Him." 1 John 3:5, 6. Here is the true test. If we abide in Christ, if the love of God dwells in us, our feelings, our thoughts, our purposes, our actions, will be in harmony with the will of God as expressed in the precepts of His holy law. *Steps to Christ 61*

Comment: "Once we commit a sin after justification, we have to be justified (receive pardon) again." One implication of this might be that if we die with unconfessed sin then we are damned. Was that intended or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, if we die with known unconfessed sin, then we are condemned. That's why the apostles repeatedly warned that he who thinks himself standing should take heed lest he fall. Then again, scarcely a righteous is saved, and so on

Comment: When Christ suffered for sins he suffered for _all_ of the sins of those whom he redeemed. Those who _receive_ this redemption (in penitence and faith, through the Holy Spirit) are said to be _justified_. Whom _he called_ them he also _justified_. Your idea of constant re-justification is thoroughly legal and the concept is _nowhere_ to be seen in scripture. This is _contrary_ to the gospel and leads people into horrific depression and despair.

Comment: KJV Ezekiel 33:12
12 Therefore, thou son of man, say unto the children of thy people, The righteousness of the righteous shall not deliver him in the day of his transgression: as for the wickedness of the wicked, he shall not fall thereby in the day that he turneth from his wickedness; neither shall the righteous be able to live for his righteousness in the day that he sinneth.

Comment: I am not talking about constant rejustification. Rather forgiveness or justification from sin when a righteous man sins.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't agree with @OneFace at all on this. We're saved by God's grace and nothing else. If I could lose my salvation just because I died at an inopportune, brief moment of known, unconfessed sin, before I came to my senses and repented, then it would completely nullify that grace.

Comment: KJV Luke 22:31-32 And the Lord said, Simon, Simon, behold, Satan hath desired to have you, that he may sift you as wheat: But I have prayed for thee, that thy faith fail not: and when thou art converted, strengthen thy brethren.

Comment: Peter had to be *converted* after his fall. He had to repent and be rejustified after his sin according to Jesus.

Comment: @IanGoldby Those who are born if God will not commit sin. Those who commit sin are not of God. See 1 John 3.

Comment: @OneFace 'converted' here means 'repented' or 'turned back'. Compare any number of other reputable translations. Nothing about rejustification. You've laid that interpretation on top - it's not found in the text.

Comment: @OneFace To me, Hebrews 6:4‭–‬6 indicates that "rejustification" is impossible—and that, if you are correct, then any Christian who sins at any time would be forever cut off from God. I presume you interpret it differently, and I'm (truly) curious how.

Comment: @IanGoldby When a person repents, it means they acknowledge they have sinned. It means they are not righteous anymore (if they had been righteous before their sin eg. Peter) as sin and righteousness cannot coexist, thus the need for repentance. When that person repents and confesses, then God forgives their sin which is the same as justification. Once forgiven (or re-forgiven) they stand just before God and it is God who justifies the sinner. In other words forgiveness and justification are one and the same. Each time a person is pardoned, he/she gets rejustified

Comment: @OneFace I hesitate to continue this probably pointless thread, but I'll just say that when we sin we don't suddenly stop being righteous because _it isn't our good behaviour that makes us righteous_ - righteousness is something that God 'credits' to us when we trust him (Gal 3:6 etc). Right behaviour, repentance and confession are all really important for us Christians, but righteousness is from God alone.